# iwlwifi failing with error code -2

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, fedora, kernel

On fedora my wifi isn't working. I tried re installing it but that didn't work. When I perform a dmesg | grep wifi I get errors:

```
[   15.680914] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode failed with error -2
[   15.680925] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode failed with error -2
[   15.680928] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode' failed.
[   15.680936] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7260-11.ucode failed with error -2
[   15.680939] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-7260-11.ucode' failed.
[   15.680946] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode failed with error -2
[   15.680949] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode' failed.
[   15.680951] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: no suitable firmware found!
```

What causes this problem. I can't find the error code definition.

Answer (score 2):

It only means the driver cannot upload the suitable firmware. For Intel cards the firmware is located in a package called `iwlwifi-firmware`, independent of distro. Just install the package from the repos and your wifi will start working.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for the fast answer. Where can I find such a package for fedora? Google isn't helpfull

Comment: @user2074487 This link will help you: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/7863/how-do-i-search-for-and-install-software-packages-in-fedora/

Comment: If I search for "iwlwifi" in dnf I get no results. That is the thing that I find strange.

Comment: @user2074487 You can find it here, https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/package/iwlwifi-firmware/

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by manualy updating the kernel-firmware package in fedora by using the [git](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git) .